# What is transition restriction in the discussion of HMM?

Tags: hidden-markov-model

What is `transition restriction` in the discussion of HMM?

Does that effect HMM algorithms?

Comment: read this one- https://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/asr/2012-13/asr03-hmmgmm-4up.pdf

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing but the transition probabilities perhaps. Next hidden states purely dependent on last states' participation probabilities and transition probabilities. So movement is restricted by transition matrix. It may also apply on emission probabilities( output values).